# Помогите убрать в url php кирилический домен

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, кириллица

Есть определенные страницы статические типа контакты.php и т.д. и страницы с собственным url, которые генерируется при добавления в базу, например: домен.ру/категория/урл-который-генирируется

В .htaccess есть вот такое:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^категория/([^/]*)$ /категория.php?cat(таблица базы)=$1 [L]
```

(На латинском домене работает всё)

Так вот, если в таком виде, то работают страницы, которые генерируются, а контакты.php без .php вылетает в 404, но если сделать вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

контакты.php работают как домен.ру/контакты.php и домен.ру/контакты , а вто страницы, которые генерируются, вылетают (браузер показывает 500 ошибку)

Есть тут кто в теме такого развала?

Comment: Реально - согласование кодировок: входной, серверной, РНР-ной. Смотрите, по GET-у приходит "категория". - В какой оно кодировке? (Хорошо, если в заголовках указано)

Comment: хорошо что я ничего не понял

Comment: Как раз правил коммент...

Comment: Дальше Сервер передает на РНР параметр `?cat(таблица базы)=$1`. Но Сервер и РНР - разные проги. И настройки кодировки у них разные (может быть). - Согласовывайте...

Comment: весь сайт в ютф=8

Comment: Сайт - это что? РНР? Апач? Анализ заголовков запроса? См. процесс в целом...

Comment: Скажу так: я ничего не понял, сайт написан полность на php sql java. Во всех файлах <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> можно конкретнее пацьцем ткнуть , если не трудно

Comment: Э-э-э, так чтоб пальцем...  Сервер принимает биты запроса. Он их декодирует. Хорошо, если в запросе есть `charset` (или тп). А если нет? это раз!

Comment: Может тут:
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
header ('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

mysql_query( 'SET NAMES utf8' );

Comment: Дальше Сервер обрабатывает СТРОКУ запроса на соответствие шаблону (`RewriteRule`). И если совпадает (???) то идет передача в РНР. А там все по-новому...

Comment: `mysql` - это позже. Пока идет Серверная обработка

Comment: а почему латинские домены работают?

Comment: у них все кодировки одинаковы